# How to access the sub Childs in a xml file in python?

Tags: python, xml, dataframe, xml-parsing

I am working with extraction data from xml files, I want to extract the questionid, message, subquestionid, in annotation I want to extract focus and type and that's what I am stuck, It is easily appending subquestionId but when appending focus and type, it is not appending anything, any help would be highly appreciated.

```
for child in root:
    if child.tag == "NLM-QUESTION":
        for name, value in child.attrib.items():
            if name == "questionid":
                quesid.append(value)
    for subchild in child:
        if subchild.tag == "MESSAGE":
            message.append(subchild.text)
        for subhild1 in subchild:
            if subchild.tag == "SUB-QUESTIONS":
                for subchild2 in subchild:
                    if subchild2.tag == "SUB-QUESTION":
                        for name, value in subchild2.attrib.items():
                            if name == "subqid":
                                subquestionId.append(value)
                        for subchild3 in subchild2:
                            for subchild4 in subchild3:
                                if subchild4.tag == "ANNOTATION":
                                    for name, value in subchild4.attrib.items():
                                        if name == "focus":
                                            focus.append(value)
                                        if name == "type":
                                            type.append(value)
```

I have highlighted which I want to extract, you can see in the image  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YX458.png)

Comment: 1) share a **VALID** xml document  (as text - not image)2) explain what is the information you try to extract from it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.